# Turn String into Mongoose Model

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm learning how to make Mongoose models in Express right now and was wondering if there is a way to convert a string into a matching model.

For instance, if I have a Mongoose model called "User" and a variable like **const name = "User"**, is there a way to convert the string "User" into a User model? Specifically, is there a way to make the following code work?

```
const name = 'User';

name.findByIdAndUpdate()
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose this was the model:

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({ name: 'string' });
const User = mongoose.model('User', schema);
```

```
const name = 'User';
```

Now use the model to construct a document:

```
const user = new User({ name });
user.save(function (err) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  // saved!
});
```

or

```
User.create({ name }, function (err, user) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  // saved!
});
```

or

```
const user = await User.create({ name });
```

Now you can use:

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(user.id, { ... }, { ... });
```

Reference: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html.

Comment: This does not answer the question...

Answer (score 0):

You can turn a string into a model like so:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const name = 'User';

mongoose.model(name).findByIdAndUpdate()
```

This would be useful if you have multiple types such as product types where product type could be a mongoose discriminator.

```
exports.addProduct = async (req, res, next) => {
  // Rental, Lodge, One, Group
  const { productType } = req.body;

  await mongoose
    .model(productType)
    .create(req.body)
    .then((product) => {
      res.status(200).json({
        message: "Product successfully created",
        product: product,
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res.status(400).json({
        message: "Product not created",
        error: error.mesage,
      });
    });
};
```